# ClosedXML use "items" Expression in multiple worksheets with different data

Tags: c#, closedxml, closedxml.report

I am currently working with ClosedXML and I use the Expression "items" to auto-map data into my table like so:

```cs
using var workBook = new XLWorkbook(exportTemplateFile);

var list1 = workBook.Worksheet("List1");

var template = new XLTemplate(exportTemplateFile);

template.AddVariable("items", _appState.FirstDataSource);
template.Generate();
template.SaveAs(Path.Combine(generatedExportFolders, "MyFile.xlsx"));
```

Inside the `FirstDataSource` I have properties like "Data1", "Data2", "Data3" and so on. The template file looks something like this:

**Worksheet "List1"**

[image]

Then I have a `_appState.SecondDataSource` with properties called "NewData1", "NewData2" and "NewData3".

**Worksheet "List2"**

[image]

Now I want to do the same for the second worksheet called "List2", but I can't use "items" again, and as far as I know, it is the only expression to do that kind of auto-mapping.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?